# CollectionView with UIScrollView as a cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a collection view with a uiscrollview in each cell, and each scrollview has some photos in it.

CollectionView is vertically scrollable, and each cell is horizontally scrollable.

NOTE: Pictures are clickable buttons!

I want to make it this way:

If user clicks on an image in any cell, it should expand and appear as a pop-up over collective view. Checking which button has been pressed is getting pretty difficult. Is there any easier solutions to observe clicks and its origin?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Target-Action approach to handle the taps you can simply pass a selector with the parameter like

`@objc func handleButtonTap(_ button: UIButton)`

`button` here is the reference to the button tapped.

You can add target to your button using:

`button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleButtonTap), for: .touchUpInside)`

EDIT:

If you want to check the IndexPath you can provide additional param `forEvent: UIEvent` in a selector and use this event along with following extension

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func indexPath(forEvent: UIEvent) -> IndexPath? {
       return forEvent.allTouches?
           .first
           .map  { $0.location(in: self) }
           .flatMap { indexPathForItem(at: $0) }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I also thought about selectors. With selectors I can find which button has been clicked exactly. But, how am I supposed to know where this button is located? I mean, the row in collection view and the number (?) in uiscrollview?

Comment: I'm thinking about the customisation of a button. Perhaps, I need to create some kind of UIButtonX that has additional parameters that can be added to it, and later read by selector. But still not the  best way, I think.

Comment: Or the easiest way is to add a tag to each button. But still, there should be a better solution.

Comment: I will edit my answer in a second to provide a way to get the indexPath

Comment: Thank you for your edit. But, I think this is not exactly what I wanted, I'm afraid.

Comment: You've asked for the way to get the indexPath and the number in scrollView. You can achieve the former with my solution. As for the latter, since scrollView does not provide any specific ordered layout you can either associate a tag with the button equal to the position or based on the button frame determine the position in its superview. I'd suggest using tags for simplicity.